# Automatically publishing WMS/WFS in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, wms, wfs

Does any one know how to automate publishing of a WMS or WFS Layer in Geoserver given any data source (vector shape-files) using script or programming language (preferably Python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [Geoserver REST API](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/) and the python wrapper [gsconfig](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/gsconfig) for the REST API.

Comment: The documentation for python is less, do you know any other source for reference